# Javascript call to ajax method with string parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
ajaxPost("Service1.svc/json/MyMethod", { "string" : "ana" }, bareResultWcfDate);

public Human MyMethod(string custName)
    {
        Human x = new Human();
        x.name = custName;
        return x;
    }
```

What to put instead of the "string" in the first line?
Every example I've seen on the internet hasn't got primitive types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, given the Ajax call you are making, it creates a query string

```
string=ana
```

and since it is a POST request, it sends that as the body of the post request.

If it were a GET request, it would concatenate the query string to the URL like this

```
Service1.svc/json/MyMethod?string=ana
```

Comment: Can you please see this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618052/wcf-service-restful

Answer (score 0):

There is no type declaration for HTTP request params. That first part 'string' is not a data type but the parameter name. i.e. it is sending a parameter named 'string' with value 'ana' to the server.

Comment: And what should I put instead "string"?

Comment: You can give any param name you prefer. For ex: 'custName' - How does you server side code get the HTTP POST params and pass it to your handler?

Comment: If possible, share a link to your app. I can help you further only if i see the code.

Comment: Well, i meant the JS code :) I have not much idea about asp.net anyway, so i wont be able to help with the server side. BTW, you can remove the file from mediafire.

Comment: You have the js code in my question. What more do you need to know?

Comment: Ok, firstly 404 usually refers to a not found error, i.e. it might be worth investigating the URL sent to the server using fiddler (network monitoring tool), or firebug's Net panel. If you see something wrong in the URL that's being sent, that's the issue. Otherwise, you will need to dig deeper into how your server side resolves the request and passes it on to your request handler.