# Wcf service RESTful

Tags: wcf, json, post, get

I made my method with post like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
List<Human> GetHuman(UserEnteredName humanName);
```

The UserEnteredName class has just one property - string.

And it works. But, I need to make it to be get, not post.

I tried with this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method= "GET", UriTemplate = "GetHuman?username={John}", 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

But it doesn't work. What do I need to change?

Comment: post the error.. what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @andreapier The error is 500 Internal server error.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to get some json from a domain which is not the base one? ie: your base domain is www.mydomain.com and you are making the ajax call from inner.mydomain.com?

Comment: @andreapier I tried using UriTemplate = "Service1.svc/json/GetHuman?custName=John", still no results.

Comment: I just want to know if your are trying to go against the same origin policy. In this case you need to use jsonP and not classic json. Let me know. By the way, adrift is correct, try that before

Comment: @andreapier OMG yes, for post methods i use jsonP

Comment: good, i guess you already have your web.config configured to use allow-same-origin-policy right?

Comment: @andreapier Well since my web.config is ok for post methods, it should be ok for get methods, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `UriTemplate`, your method would have to look something like

```
Human GetHuman(string John)
```

I suspect you are mistakenly putting a possible parameter value in your `UriTemplate`.  Try something like

```
[WebInvoke(Method= "GET", UriTemplate = "GetHuman?username={userName}", 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Human GetHuman(string userName)
```

Also, for `GET`, you can use the [`WebGetAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx), which is slightly cleaner.

---

I would change your method to take a `string` parameter and construct the `UserEnteredName` instance in the method body.  It may be possible to use your `UserEnteredName` type as a parameter if it uses the `TypeConverterAttribute`, but I have never done this, so I can't say how easy (or not) it is.  See the [WCF Web HTTP Programming Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172.aspx), specifically the *UriTemplate Query String Parameters and URLs* section.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work
My method looks like this:
List<Human> GetHuman(UserEnteredName humanName);
but UserEnteredName is a class which contains string property userName

Comment: i'm surprised you can even get it to compile... how can you pass a string instead of a UserEnteredName? Maybe you wrote a simplified example for us? Or maybe you can try a wrapper for your GetHuman methos that takes a string as input parameter

Comment: @andreapier I updated my question - about the UserEnteredName class.